# How do I make a rainbow on a page?

Tags: html, css

I saw the following website:
[Photo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrR9i.png)

I was wondering how I create something similar to this? The rainbow effect really got me and I've been looking for the past 30 minutes but couldn't find anything. I basically want circles surrounding from the bottom of the page.

Comment: see `radial-gradient` with color stops. when color stops are the same, it makes an edge without the colors blending into each other

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What you can see are stacked (color-filled) circles that have a drop shadow around them. These can be created quite easily in an SVG image. Tools like Inkscape can help you design them.

Comment: @cornonthecob What do you mean exactly? I basically want to eventually put icons inside of every 'circle'

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Is it possible in pure CSS aswell? I eventually want to eventually put icons inside

Comment: see https://css-tricks.com/radial-gradient-recipes/ and also don't forget you can have multiple background images

Comment: @cornonthecob That's not exactly what I want since these are just some colors

Comment: true, perhaps you could look into multiple backgrounds for your icons as well - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: @cornonthecob That's also not what I want, I want to have these curved divs all around each other and I want to be able to put content inside. Not just background and colors.

Comment: then I would probably recommend using z-index and border-radius and absolute positioning, which, even though it can be irritating, will let you have content inside it

Comment: @cornonthecob rip responsiveness lol

Comment: does https://codepen.io/cornonthecob/pen/mdadvgB which I just made help actually (no absolute positions needed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following discussions in the comments, I can see you want to add things directly into each part of the rainbow, and also maintain responsiveness.

So (despite what I said before in the comments, although those solutions would work fine in lots of cases) I would recommend in your scenario to actually use `position:static` elements and no `radial-gradients` or absolute positions, but instead to use `border-radius` and `box-shadow` to achieve this.

`border-radius` in this case makes the top curvy like a rainbow is, and `box-shadow` fills the gaps that would be in-between the elements normally. I've used CSS custom properties to make it neater.

```css
.one,
.two,
.three,
.four {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 60px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 50px;
  background: var(--color);
  box-shadow: 0 50px var(--color);
  text-align: center;
}

.one {
  --color: #ff0022;
}

.two {
  --color: #ff3344;
}

.three {
  --color: #335522;
}

.four {
  --color: #992244;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">hi</div>
<div class="two">hello everybody</div>
<div class="three">greetings</div>
<div class="four">goodbye</div>
```

https://codepen.io/cornonthecob/pen/mdadvgB

Note that if you want it to look more rainbow-shaped, you should change the border-radius values for each element to perfect the shape, however this is only something you can really do in your actual project once you've adapted this solution to your needs.

Comment: Appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a combination of `background: radial-gradient` and `position: relative` for the parent and `position: absolute` for the children and then, using `left` and `top` you can position your icons wherever you want. If you use percentages, then it will work on a variety of screens.

```css
div#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, red 0, blue, green, yellow, purple, orange 100%);
}

div#container span {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <span>1</span>
    <span style="top: 15%; left: 10%;">2</span>
    <span style="top: 25%; left: 20%;">3</span>
    <span style="top: 28%; left: 50%;">4</span>
    <span style="top: 38%; left: 65%;">5</span>
    <span style="top: 50%; left: 25%;">6</span>
    <span style="top: 50%; left: 75%;">7</span>
    <span style="top: 75%; left: 50%;">8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pure CSS solutions, then as @cornonthecob recommended the best way would be the gradients approach with hard color stops.

See the snippet below for a sample implementation.

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
}
.container > div {
  height: 400px;
}
.container > div {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at bottom center,
    #ec407a,
    #ec407a 20%,
    #7e57c2 20%,
    #7e57c2 40%,
    #42a5f5 40%,
    #42a5f5 60%,
    #26a69a 60%,
    #26a69a 80%,
    #9ccc65 80%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```